# Get the method and url from an XMLHttpRequest instance

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Suppose you do

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/test');
xhr.send();
```

The question is, is there a way, to extract url and method from that `xhr` object?

For example, when the response is received you can get the url: `xhr.responseURL`. But can I get the method too (there is no `xhr.responseMethod`)

In my case I cannot patch the `XMLHttpRequest` prototype and store these values, I have to deal with the instance only. Any suggestions?

Comment: _"I cannot patch the XMLHttpRequest prototype and store these values, I have to deal with the instance only."_ - Why?

Comment: In my case it is a chrome extension. At the time the extension has injected the script to patch XMLHttpRequest, it might be too late and the call might already be made, but the response is not yet received.